# Wraping foreach loop into div doesnt work

Tags: php

```
function news($newsarray) {
    $str='';

        '<div>foreach($newsarray as $value) 
        {
            $str.="<h3>{$value['title']}</h3>";
            $str.="<h4>{$value['content']}</h4>";
        }</div>'

    return $str;
    }
    echo news($newsarray);
```

I want to wrap it up the foreach loop into div, but it doesn't work, I know it is something with the escaping but I'm new in programming and I have hard times with the documentation. I've asked a similar question earlier, but I'm really confused, sorry for asking again.

on the localhost it says

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `title` (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\news\news.php on line 17

Comment: Please use the [WYSIWYG](http://xkcd.com/1341/) editor buttons to format your content.

Comment: Also: You just asked a question about exactly that problem: String concatenation. Please take your time to read the provided links and **learn** from the provided answers. Thanks.

Comment: You have a mismatched quote. Look at the syntax highlighting. Format your code properly and use an IDE and these problems become easier to diagnose.

Comment: First do: $str = '<div>'; Then, do your foreach loop and finish with $str .= '</div>';

Comment: thanks again, it worked, i will read more and learn from provaded answers as you told. Thx again! @kaiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function news($newsarray) { 
   $str='<div>';

   foreach($newsarray as $value) 
   {
       $str.="<h3>{$value['title']}</h3>";
       $str.="<h4>{$value['content']}</h4>";
   }
   $str.='</div>';

return $str;
}
echo news($newsarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have your code placed in the string variable as well.
Maybe this is what you were trying to do:

```
function news($newsarray) { 
    $str='<div>';

    foreach($newsarray as $value) {
        $str .= "<h3>{$value['title']}</h3>";
        $str .= "<h4>{$value['content']}</h4>";
    }

    $str .= '</div>';

    return $str;
} 

echo news($newsarray);
```